# What is meant with "Solving iteratively" here?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Consider the equation
$$
\frac{1}{2}(f')^2=f^3+\frac{1}{2}cf^2+Af+B\equiv F(f).
$$
Suppose $F$ has a simple zero $f_1$, then we can approximate, as $f\to f_1$,
$$
(f')^2=2 F'(f_1)(f-f_1)+ O((f-f_1)^2).
$$

Now it is said that we can solve this iteratively to get
$$
f=f_1+\frac{1}{2}(\xi-\xi_1)^2F'(f_1)+O((\xi-\xi_1)^4)\tag{*}
$$
as $\xi\to\xi_1$, where $f(\xi_1)=f_1$.

What is meant by *solving iteratively* and how does one finally get $(*)$?

Don‘t get it, maybe you have an idea?

Here is the text passage I am referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "iteratively" refers to the conversion of the error term from a power in $f-f_1$ to a power in $\xi-\xi_1$.

So in first approximation you take $f$ as the non-constant solution to the simplified equation $f'^2=2F'(f)(f-f_1)$, which gives $f-f_1=\frac{F'(f)}2(\xi-\xi_1)^2$.

Now inserting this and a little handwave gives that $O((f-f_1)^2)=O((\xi-\xi_1)^4)$, as claimed.

---

If you want to make this a little more exact, you need to establish a converging fixed-point iteration
One way to do this is to take the derivative of the given equation to get
$$
f''=F'(f),
$$
and transform this into an integration formula
$$
f(x)=f_1+f'(\xi_1)(\xi-\xi_1)+\int_{\xi_1}^x(\xi-s)f''(s)\,ds\\
f(x)=f_1+\int_{\xi_1}^x(x-s)F'(f(s))\,ds
$$
Now treat this as fixed-point formula and apply the a-priory error estimate.  Or use a Grönwall-like argument to estimate the difference between the exact solution and the solution of the simplified equation

Comment: I have a short question to this. If I do consider $(f')^2=2F'(f_1)(f-f_1)$ and solve this by separation of variables, I get the equation $$\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{f-f_1}}{\sqrt{F'(f_1)}}=\xi+C\Leftrightarrow f=f_1+\frac{1}{2}(\xi+C)^2 F'(f_1)$$, so how do I get the $(\xi-\xi_1)^2$ instead of $(\xi+C)^2$?

Comment: Because the solution you approximate has $f(\xi_1)=f_1$.

Comment: You mean that in the separation of variables, we integrate from $\xi_1$ to $\xi$, i.e. $$\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{f(\xi)-f_1}}{\sqrt{F'(f_1)}}=\int_{\xi_1}^\xi\frac{df}{\sqrt{2 F'(f_1)(f-f_1)}}=\int_{\xi_1}^\xi\, ds = (\xi-\xi_1)?$$

Comment: Yes, or just inserting the IC gives $C=-\xi_1$.